# Who is the young pilot of the Jedi’s ship at the beginning of "The Phantom Menace”?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-phantom-menace

Who was the pilot who flew Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan to negotiate with the Trade Federation?

Comment: If you could [edit] in an image of who you are asking about it would make this easier to identify.

Comment: I'd be inclined to edit the title to be less wordy and more specific (ie: "Who is this pilot....") but...I'm not

Answer (score 10):

According to [her article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maoi_Madakor) on Wookieepedia, the pilot's name is Maoi Madakor.

[image: Maoi Madakor]

She was one of two crew members on board when the ship, the [Radiant VII](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Radiant_VII) was destroyed. The other crew member was [Antidar Williams](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Antidar_Williams)

[image: Antidar Williams]

Comment: So its not a child flying it I would say?

Comment: Probably not, though I can see where someone could make that mistake.

Comment: The actress playing her was born in 1972, so she was actually around 27 during the movie. Her character was probably meant to be around that age too, not a teenager.

Comment: Pic 1 is an Irish actress who was in Pulp Fiction hanging out with the drug dealers girlfriend!

Comment: @Seamusthedog She is! Bronagh Gallagher.

Comment: You may want to note that she was first named in the 2017 Visual Encyclopedia; https://i.stack.imgur.com/iArfA.png. Before that she was simply "The Captain"; https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html

Comment: @Seamusthedog "Which one's Trudi? The one with all the s*** in her face?"

Comment: @Buzz THATS MY WIFE!!!! (Smile)